# Return SQL subquery as boolean field?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, boolean

I would like to do something like this (mix of sql with pseudocode):

let's assume for this example that there is a separate phone number table:

**person:** person_id, person_name, person_lastName
**phone_number:** phonenmb_id, phonenmb_number, phonenmb_person_id

`SELECT p.name, p.lastName, hasPhoneNumber = hasPhoneNumber(someNumber)`

In the example i would like to get some data from a person, and given a certain phone number, return TRUE if the person has that number on it's number list, or FALSE if it doesn't.

If anyone can provide a hint on how to do this directly with Doctrine and DQL it'd be awesome, otherwise i'll just translate it to DQL myself.

Comment: i would have to put a ton of data if i add were to add sample data... because my case is a lot more complex than this. it involves 4 or 5 tables... i just want to know how to  return a variable with true or false if an id exits in another set of id's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach is to outer join to the phone number table using the person_id and the phone number, and then check if the outer join was satisfied to calculate the boolean.

Example using your schema:

```
SELECT p.person_name, p.person_lastName, 
  (pn.phonenmb_id IS NOT NULL) as hasPhoneNumber
FROM person p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN phone_number pn on pn.phonenmb_person_id = p.person_id 
                                 and pn.phonenmb_number = someNumber
GROUP BY p.person_name, p.person_lastName
```

Comment: thanks! will give this a try when i get home from work and i'll let you know